# Why GAN is unable to generate samples from some distributions?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I'm tried to implement basic GAN in Keras, based on [this](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/gan/gan.py) implementation.

If I sample points on parabola GAN is converges and able to produce samples from this distribution, but if for example I sample points on circle it fails. I wonder why it's hard for GAN? How it can be fixed?

Here is learning process for parabola:
[image]

Here is learning process for circle:
[image]

Here is the code to reproduce:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import os
import shutil
from datetime import datetime

from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam

from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

# Derived from original code https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/gan/gan.py

def print_env_info():
    print('-' * 60)
    import keras
    print('keras.__version__', keras.__version__)
    print('-' * 60)
    import tensorflow as tf
    print('tf.__version__', tf.__version__)
    print('-' * 60)

class GAN():
    def __init__(self):
        self.latent_dim = 128

        optimizer = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)

        # Build and compile the discriminator
        self.discriminator = self.build_discriminator()
        self.discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['accuracy'])

        # Build the generator
        self.generator = self.build_generator()

        # The generator takes noise as input and generates imgs
        z = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        img = self.generator(z)

        # For the combined model we will only train the generator
        self.discriminator.trainable = False

        # The discriminator takes generated images as input and determines validity
        validity = self.discriminator(img)

        # The combined model  (stacked generator and discriminator)
        # Trains the generator to fool the discriminator
        self.combined = Model(z, validity)
        self.combined.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)

        # Tensorboard writer
        log_dir = "logs/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        self.writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir)

    def build_generator(self):

        model = Sequential()

        model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=self.latent_dim))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=2))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(Dense(2, activation='tanh'))

        model.summary()

        noise = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        img = model(noise)

        return Model(noise, img)

    def build_discriminator(self):

        model = Sequential()

        model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=2))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=2))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        model.summary()

        img = Input(shape=(2, ))
        validity = model(img)

        return Model(img, validity)

    def generate_dataset(self, n_samples=10000):
        # # V1: y = x^2
        x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=n_samples)
        y = x ** 2
        data = np.stack([x, y], axis=1)

        # V2: x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 = 1
        # angle = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=n_samples) * (np.pi * 2)
        # x = np.cos(angle)
        # y = np.sin(angle)
        # data = np.stack([x, y], axis=1)

        # V3: swiss roll
        # data, _ = datasets.make_swiss_roll(n_samples=n_samples, noise=0.0, random_state=0)
        # data = np.stack([data[:, 0], data[:, 2]], axis=1)
        # data = data - np.min(data, axis=0)
        # data = data / np.max(data, axis=0)
        # data = 2 * data - 1.0

        # # V4:
        # data, _ = datasets.make_moons(n_samples=n_samples, shuffle=False, noise=None, random_state=0)
        # data = data - np.min(data, axis=0)
        # data = data / np.max(data, axis=0)
        # data = 2 * data - 1.0

        return data

    def summary_image(self, tensor):
        import io
        from PIL import Image

        tensor = tensor.astype(np.uint8)

        height, width, channel = tensor.shape
        image = Image.fromarray(tensor)
        output = io.BytesIO()
        image.save(output, format='PNG')
        image_string = output.getvalue()
        output.close()
        return tf.Summary.Image(height=height,
                                width=width,
                                colorspace=channel,
                                encoded_image_string=image_string)

    def get_visualization(self, epoch):
        def generate_fake_data(n_samples):
            noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (n_samples, self.latent_dim))
            X_hat = self.generator.predict(noise)
            x = X_hat[:, 0]
            y = X_hat[:, 1]
            return x, y

        def save_figure():
            x_fake, y_fake = generate_fake_data(n_samples=100)
            data = self.generate_dataset(n_samples=1000)
            x_real, y_real = data[:, 0], data[:, 1]

            axes = plt.gca()
            axes.set_xlim([-1, 1])
            axes.set_ylim([-1, 1])
            axes.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
            plt.scatter(x_real, y_real, s=1, color='b', alpha=0.2)
            plt.scatter(x_fake, y_fake, s=1, color='r')
            plt.savefig(f'images/{epoch}.png')
            plt.close()

        save_figure()

        image = cv2.imread(f'images/{epoch}.png')
        image = self.summary_image(image)

        return image


    def train(self, epochs, batch_size, sample_interval):
        # Load the dataset
        X_train = self.generate_dataset()

        print('X_train.shape', X_train.shape)

        # Adversarial ground truths
        valid = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
        fake = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))

        for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs), total=epochs):
            # ---------------------
            #  Train Discriminator
            # ---------------------

            # Select a random batch of images
            idx = np.random.randint(0, X_train.shape[0], batch_size)
            imgs = X_train[idx]

            noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, self.latent_dim))

            # Generate a batch of new images
            gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(noise)

            # Train the discriminator
            d_loss_real = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(imgs, valid)
            d_loss_fake = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_imgs, fake)
            d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)

            # ---------------------
            #  Train Generator
            # ---------------------

            noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, self.latent_dim))

            # Train the generator (to have the discriminator label samples as valid)
            g_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch(noise, valid)

            # Print the progress
            # print ("%d [D loss: %f, acc.: %.2f%%] [G loss: %f]" % (epoch, d_loss[0], 100*d_loss[1], g_loss))

            if epoch % sample_interval == 0:
                image_summary = tf.Summary(value=[tf.Summary.Value(tag='fake', image=self.get_visualization(epoch))])
                self.writer.add_summary(image_summary, epoch)

            if epoch % sample_interval == 0:
                summary = tf.Summary(value=[
                    tf.Summary.Value(tag="loss/D_loss", simple_value=d_loss[0]),
                ])
                self.writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)

                summary = tf.Summary(value=[
                    tf.Summary.Value(tag="D_loss/D_loss_real", simple_value=d_loss_real[0]),
                ])
                self.writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)

                summary = tf.Summary(value=[
                    tf.Summary.Value(tag="D_loss/D_loss_fake", simple_value=d_loss_fake[0]),
                ])
                self.writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)

                summary = tf.Summary(value=[
                    tf.Summary.Value(tag="loss/Acc", simple_value=100*d_loss[1]),
                ])
                self.writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)

                summary = tf.Summary(value=[
                    tf.Summary.Value(tag="D_loss/Acc_real", simple_value=100*d_loss_real[1]),
                ])
                self.writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)

                summary = tf.Summary(value=[
                    tf.Summary.Value(tag="D_loss/Acc_fake", simple_value=100*d_loss_fake[1]),
                ])
                self.writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)

                summary = tf.Summary(value=[
                    tf.Summary.Value(tag="loss/G_loss", simple_value=g_loss),
                ])
                self.writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_env_info()

    if os.path.exists('logs'):
        shutil.rmtree('logs')

    if os.path.exists('images'):
        shutil.rmtree('images')
    os.makedirs('images')

    gan = GAN()
    gan.train(epochs=10000, batch_size=32, sample_interval=200)
```

Comment: Your question can only be answered by theoretical research, its not a programming problem, so it is very unlikely that you will get an answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the accuracy plots you have in Tensorboard, your principal problem here is with the discriminator. Because its accuracy oscillates around 50-60% and doesn't improve. And this is very bad because the generator is downstream and can't train until the discriminator achieves decent accuracy. So what is wrong with the discriminator?

First, it is the way you train it. You feed it positive and negative samples in two separate batches. This can generate gradients pushing your model coefficients randomly in opposite directions with very poor convergence. If you combine both types of samples in a single batch, convergence will improve significantly.

Second, the batch size. 32 random points around a circle is too little for the model to feel the difference against 32 random points. You need to have a batch size of at least 256.

Third, the number of neurons in hidden layers. Actually, you have too many neurons for such simple data in both generator and discriminator. Having too many of them in the discriminator doesn't seem to do much harm, but having too many neurons in the generator makes it too unstable, the discriminator each time receives different training data and this is one more reason why it fails to train properly. If you put 16 and 32 hidden neurons instead of 64 and 128 into the generator, it will be much better.

And the last point: it is not only the circular form that makes your circle difficult to learn but also its size. It has a radius of 1, and 1 is the saturation value of your generator, so it is very easy for it to produce values around 1. And this makes additional trouble for the generator: it starts receiving fake data too close to the true data before it achieves decent accuracy.

To summarize:

1. Combine true and fake data into a single batch.
2. Use a larger batch size (at least 256).
3. Reduce the number of neurons at least in the generator (e.g. to 16 and 32).

Enjoy the result:
[image: Training result]

And one more thing: it is better to ask such questions in this community https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Can you elaborate on concept of 'saturation value'? why it's easy for generator to produce values around 1? do you mean that generator can predict logits, lest say in range `[4, inf]` that will produce `tanh(x)~1.0` and it still will match some points on circle boundary near 1.0 anyway?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.